# Using ajaxComplete in view pagination

Tags: views, ajax, paging

I have (drupal 7) **view** where I have **pagination with Ajax** enabled.
When any pager item is clicked I want to perform certain thing **after the view is reloaded with ajax**.
I am trying the following code:

```
(function($){
Drupal.behaviors.myBehavior = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function( event, request, settings ) {
        console.log("Ajax Completed");
    });
   }
 };


})(jQuery);
```

There is no output form console.log(). What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You're missing 1 line, after the last line, you should have another line with `})(jQuery);`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Updated now. It was missing while pasting the code. It's there in the actual site but still not working.

Comment: I think in this case, since you're using `.ajaxComplete` you have to do it without the Drupal behaviors, so remove line 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24299/drupal-add-js-within-ajax-callback). Based on @djayp34's answer, this is how I achieved what I wanted.

Basically the idea is:
Drupal does not support adding a JS snippet through `drupal_add_js()` or any other function at **AJAX callback**. So what we are doing here is:

**Step 1:** We register/load that particular JS code during normal page load.
In template.php:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  drupal_add_js(
    'Drupal.ajax.prototype.commands.myFunction = function(ajax, response, status){
       //The JS code that needs to be called after completion of ajax
      }',
      'inline'
     ); 
}
```

**Step 2:** We call that JS code when we want it. Here we want it to be called during AJAX callback.

In module file.

```
function MYMODULE_views_ajax_data_alter(&$commands, $view){
  if($view->name == 'MY_VIEW'){
    $commands[] = array("command" => 'myFunction'); 
  }
}
```